# Enable only days i want in calendar picker

Tags: jquery, android, calendar

I want to show a calendar widget in android 2.3 but I only want to set some days as clickable.

I've searched for any method to do this, but not found nothing, nor any libraries that could do it.

The only other way I can think of is to include a Webview with a jquery calendar, but I don't know how I can send the days to the Webview.

Any help please?

Comment: Make your own calendar picker... You could base it on the android from the source.